# Relationship between finite moment and tail probability

Tags: probability

I wonder how do the existence of nth moment $E(|X|^n)<\infty$ implies the following limits $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^nP(|X|>x)=0$ It’s quite obvious but I want to express it in a formula way where I was stuck. I want to find out this relationship by exploring the definition of the nth moment provided by Riemann-Stieljes integral. And I separate the integral into two parts with the characteristic function $1_{|X|>x}$ and $1_{|X|<x}$. The next step I want to let x goes infinity. But I find I am lack of mathematical expression to describe the following process in a proper way. So I’m looking for help.

Comment: This has been answered many times on this site. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286404/how-is-this-done-by-dominated-convergence-theorem?noredirect=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348510/tail-probability-of-a-random-variable?noredirect=1).